# Updated Windows 10 Pro and Active Directory Users and Groups disappeared

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

In its place is something called "Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Setup Wizard".

If I go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn windows features on or off "Remote Server Administration Tools" is no longer there.

Anyone have any idea what happened and how can I get the AD app back?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a method here for updating RSAT tools in Windows 10 2004:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2dd6a001-fd72-44e2-9f3b-2faf9d993bb5/rsat-windows-10-2004?forum=win10itproapps

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out using Apps & Features > Optional Updates.  I'm surprised/not surprised Microsoft would just arbitrarily remove something that I have been using in Windows forever

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Apps & Features > Optional Updates > + Add a feature and then search for "RSAT" and install the desired features.